# AWS EC2 snapshot restore

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created a snapshot for one of my EC2 instances on AWS. Then created a new volume from it. Detached old volume and now trying to attach new volume.
With previous volume device was set to /dev/sda1 but now upon selecting instance to attach it to it automatically populates Device as /dev/sdf and gives a note: Note: Newer Linux kernels may rename your devices to /dev/xvdf through /dev/xvdp internally, even when the device name entered here (and shown in the details) is /dev/sdf through /dev/sdp.

What is the deal with this - can I proceed as is or should I amend the Device field to /dev/sda1

Comment: Change the device name to `/dev/sda1` and proceed.

Comment: thanks franklinsijo